# Wordpress Remove Date From Post Title

Tags: php, wordpress, date, title

Usually I would be able to do this without any problem, but I'm deleting some syntax here when I go ahead and remove the date from the page title in this code:

```
echo '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"] .'</a>  ' . date("F jS, Y", strtotime($recent['post_date'])) . "</h3>";
```

How do I remove the date without killing my entire page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply remove date function

```
echo '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"] .'</a> </h3>';
```

Comment: I was accidentally removing that period by mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:-

```
echo '<h3><a href="'.get_permalink($recent["ID"]).'"title="Look'.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >'.$recent["post_title"] .'</a></h3>';
```

Comment: what is the logic of copy paste my answer?

Comment: Sorry dude i didn't saw your answer. After posting it , i got to know you have already did.

Comment: don't feel sorry but was rechecking my answer that am I wrong anywhere?